# Biometric signature with DocuSign

Tags: sugarcrm, docusignapi

is it possible for the final customer to "biometrically" sign the document
with DocuSign? "biometric" meaning the capture of (unique and forensically identifiable)
parameters such as acceleration, speed and rhythm (e.g. the XYZMO technology).
If it so, is the biometric signature implemented in the DocuSign plug-in for SugarCRM?
Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Does DocuSign do signatures in this way currently? I see nothing on their web site to make me think they do.

Comment: DocuSign does not offer that functionality as of right now.

Answer (score 0):

Axel, if this question is still interesting for you, let me know. You asked this question many years ago; meanwhile the Xyzmo solution is available in many different products of Namirial - and Namirial is offering possibilities also for remote signers (in case your final customer isn't on-site at the dealer).